# Selenium cannot get all elements of a page

Tags: python, selenium

i am using selenium to go search on agoda and **scrape** all the hotel name in the page, but the output only return 2 names.

Then i tried to add a line to scroll to the bottom, now the output gives me first 2 names and last 2 names (first two from beginning, last two from bottom)

I don't understand what's the problem, i added time.sleep() for each step so the whole page should have been loaded completely. Does selenium limit by page view that it can only **scrape** those element in sight?

my code below:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

time.sleep(30)

def scrape():
    r = requests.get(current_page)

if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    print('start scraping!')
    hotel = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hotel-name')
    
    hotels = []
    
    for h in hotel:
        if hotel:
            hotels.append(h.text)
                
    print(hotels, file=open("output.txt", 'a', encoding="utf-8"))
    
scrape()
```

[Here is the page i want to **scrape**](https://www.agoda.com/pages/agoda/default/DestinationSearchResult.aspx?asq=8wUBc629jr0%2B3O%2BxycijdcaVIGtokeWrEO7ShJumN8xsNvkFkEV9bUgNnbx6%2Bx22ncbzTLOPBjT84OgAAKXmu6quf8aEKRA%2FQH%2BGoyXgowLt%2BXyB8OpN1h2WP%2BnBM%2FwNPzD%2BpaeII93w%2Bs4dMWI4QPJNbZJ8DWvRiPsrPVVBJY7ilpMPlUermwV1UKIKfuyeis3BqRkJh9FzJOs0E98zXQ%3D%3D&city=9590&cid=-142&tick=636818018163&languageId=20&userId=3c2c4cb9-ba6d-4519-8ef4-c85dfd280b8f&sessionId=d4qzq2tgymjrwsf22lnadxpc&pageTypeId=1&origin=HK&locale=zh-TW&aid=130589&currencyCode=HKD&htmlLanguage=zh-tw&cultureInfoName=zh-TW&ckuid=3c2c4cb9-ba6d-4519-8ef4-c85dfd280b8f&prid=0&checkIn=2019-01-16&checkOut=2019-01-17&rooms=1&adults=2&children=0&priceCur=HKD&los=1&textToSearch=%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA&productType=-1&travellerType=1)

Comment: fyi it's __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use below script to scroll page down until no more results appeared on page and then scrape all available names:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.agoda.com/pages/agoda/default/DestinationSearchResult.aspx?asq=8wUBc629jr0%2B3O%2BxycijdcaVIGtokeWrEO7ShJumN8xsNvkFkEV9bUgNnbx6%2Bx22ncbzTLOPBjT84OgAAKXmu6quf8aEKRA%2FQH%2BGoyXgowLt%2BXyB8OpN1h2WP%2BnBM%2FwNPzD%2BpaeII93w%2Bs4dMWI4QPJNbZJ8DWvRiPsrPVVBJY7ilpMPlUermwV1UKIKfuyeis3BqRkJh9FzJOs0E98zXQ%3D%3D&city=9590&cid=-142&tick=636818018163&languageId=20&userId=3c2c4cb9-ba6d-4519-8ef4-c85dfd280b8f&sessionId=d4qzq2tgymjrwsf22lnadxpc&pageTypeId=1&origin=HK&locale=zh-TW&aid=130589&currencyCode=HKD&htmlLanguage=zh-tw&cultureInfoName=zh-TW&ckuid=3c2c4cb9-ba6d-4519-8ef4-c85dfd280b8f&prid=0&checkIn=2019-01-16&checkOut=2019-01-17&rooms=1&adults=2&children=0&priceCur=HKD&los=1&textToSearch=%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA&productType=-1&travellerType=1')
# Get initial list of names
hotels = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'hotel-name')))

while True:
    # Scroll down to last name in list
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', hotels[-1])
    try:
        # Wait for more names to be loaded
        wait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: len(wait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'hotel-name')))) > len(hotels))
        # Update names list 
        hotels = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'hotel-name')))
    except:
        # Break the loop in case no new names loaded after page scrolled down
        break

# Print names list
print([hotel.text for hotel in hotels])
```

Comment: may i know why we need to use hotels[-1] for scrollIntoView ?

Comment: @icantcode , to load more results we need to scroll down to *currently last result*. That's why `hotels[-1]` is used